# Storing a Generic Table (with rows, columns) fields are not explicit as objects in Database Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django Project im trying to map out generic tables the number and column definitions would be different for each table

Table 1
|  Col1 | Col2 |
| ----- | -----|

Table 2
| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| ----- | ----- | ------|

These are the proposed models that I thought, not sure if this is the best way to do this or even if storing these tables in my psql  database

```
class GenericColumn(models.Model):
    given_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Given Column Name')   
   

class GenericTable(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Table Name')
    columns = models.ManyToManyField(GenericColumn, blank=True, verbose_name='Columns')
  

class GenericRow(models.Model):
    table =  models.ForeignKey(GenericTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.JSONField(null=True)
    # data being {colName: "Value"} as a JSON object
```

I did initially have a model for an individual cell but I aborted that idea as there would loads of entries in the database might get too big

I wanted to ask what would be the best way to go about this as its a bit of unusual use case as none of the fields are specified it depends on what the table is. But on the front end you would be able to edit these thats why i stored it as models rather than just keeping it all as JSON Object

Not sure the best way to go about this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: _"I did initially have a model for an individual cell but I aborted that idea as there would loads of entries in the database might get too big"_ ...this idea is probably mistaken as you have the same amount of data either way, there's nothing inherently wrong with having lots of rows.  It's hard to say whether any of this is a good idea without more details of what you're trying to achieve and how the data would be accessed. Are you building a spreadsheet?

Comment: I guess i kind of am. Im basically reading a bunch of csvs storing the data in some format for the user to check for validation issues before data is transformed and used to do some calculations down the line

Comment: You might need some way of specifying the order of the columns. That could be via a ["through" table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) on the m2m relation with an index number field, or it might be simpler to model GenericColumn more like GenericRow, with a foreign key to `table`, then the index field could be on the GenericColumn table (I'm not sure how important it is for you to model columns of the same name on different tables as the same entity... this would give up that property)